# C++ LLVM class functionality

Tags: c++, class, llvm

I'm playing around with LLVM, but now I got stuck at generating code for classes.

How would one create class functionality using LLVM?

- Are class operators handled just like functions?
- How is automated allocation handled, (like C++)?
- How to support interfaces like Java does, through virtual inheritence like C++?

Comment: What do you mean? You're writing intermediate-form LLVM bytecode by hand, or what? Well, I don't think it's meant to be used in this way, except perhaps for some critical optimisations that one might also write in Assmebly. For something as high-level as classes, one would use a suitable front-end, the most obvious being `clang++`, and write the classes in generic C++.

Comment: I'm writing a programming language, something close to very simplified Java. So I need to write the class functionality by hand to connect it to my parser.

Comment: You'll need to desugar your classes to something more low-level. Have you ever written OO code in C? It's horribly cumbersome, but works and gives you a good idea about how to implement classes in a compiler. – This question really doesn't have much to do with LLVM, then. Though in fact I think LLVM _does_ have facilities to optimise particular patterns that turn up in typical class implementations, so the tag may still be relevant. However I know nothing about this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Long Version

### General class behavior

A straightforward approach is to create structs, then model methods as regular functions that receive a pointer to a struct representing the containing class - in essence, a `this` pointer - as the first parameter. Allocation could be modeled by allocating the struct and then calling a special initializing function - the constructor, really - on the allocated data.

Inheritance could be done by building a struct which contains a special "parent" field (or fields, for multiple inheritance), that has a type identical to the type of the struct for the base class.

### Polymorphism

Read about virtual tables; I think they're the best starting point. You could find that the compiler basically:

1. Creates a static table in memory, mapping from a function "name" to its implementation,
2. Adds a pointer to the class struct that points to such a table,
3. Whenever a virtual method is called, compiles it into an indirect call which dereferences the address from the appropriate virtual table entry.

## Short Version

Write some code which uses classes in C++, then compile it to LLVM IR with Clang and look at the generated code.